# Trying to Port Forward, but my IPv4 is very strange

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, ipv4

I'm not even sure where to start here.  I am attempting to port forward.  I currently have a Motorola Surfboard and an Arris Router with extenders.  The PC that I am attempting to port forward is plugged directly into a networking panel in my home (I believe through the Motorola Surfboard).  I am able to access 192.168.0.1, however my IPv4 (found through ipconfig /all) is 67.x.x.x.  The port forwarding section of my router does not find this as a valid IP, thus making it impossible for me to port forward.

I know this post was vague, just hoping someone would have any idea of what I am talking about.

Thanks!

Comment: So... you're in New Mexico?  The 67.x.x.x seems like it's most likely your external address rather than your internal address.  Or... are you running some VPN software, that's connecting you to some point in New Mexico?  (I get New Mexico by looking up where a number of the 67.x.x.0 networks are, and they're all there.)

Comment: I'm not.  I'm in Idaho. Lol.  My IP location is showing as Iowa.  I'm not using a VPN, I made sure that I didnt connect to one, and then forget.

Comment: Well, in that case, you'll need to get someone who knows Windows a bit better than me... but those types tend to outnumber us Linux geeks 10 to 1 at least, so I'm sure one will be by presently.  Good luck.  :)

Comment: Can you provide specifics?  If I am not mistaken, Arris, own's Motorola cable modem business.  I didn't even know Arris made non-gateway hardware.

Comment: I have my Motorola modem plugged into this - https://www.homedepot.com/p/ARRIS-SURFboard-SBR-AC1900P-Wireless-Wi-Fi-Router-with-RipCurrent-G-hn-Technology-1000018/301144628?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CVF%7CSmartHome%7CMulti%7CNA%7CPLA%7CTopSKUs%7CNEW%7c71700000043519444%7c58700004578304380%7c92700038431240637&gclid=Cj0KCQiA-JXiBRCpARIsAGqF8wWBrcqlYRuTAahAEOQAo8T-2HhoZL_6HNfZ-2_BJOh1invZjgLxNwcaAh6UEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: I just dont understand why my IPv4 isn't showing as a 192, or a 10.x.x.  Using both modems was the only way I could get the extenders that came with the Arris modem to work.

Comment: Show us a network diagram with all the equipment, IPs and connections.